# Bash wildcards move command

Tags: bash, wildcard

Trying the following:
Find all files build*.tgz (it is only 1 file).
Rename to build.tgz

```
branch_name="brn1"
fil1="$(ls /home/build/branches/$branch_name/build*.tgz)"
mv $fil1 /home/build/branches/$branch_name/build.tgz
```

Getting:

```
ls: cannot access /home/build/branches/brn1/build*.tgz: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Do you have any output for just `"$(ls /home/build/branches/$branch_name)"`?

Comment: Why not just `mv /home/build/branches/$branch_name/build*.tgz /home/build/branches/$branch_name/build.tgz`?

Comment: Leon: Command does not work
mv: cannot stat `/home/build/branches/sr15.0/build*.tgz'

Comment: Inian - it brings one file name

Comment: Use `fil1=$(...)` without quotes, then `mv "$fil1" ...` _with_ quotes (in case of matching a single file). If more than one file matches, the mv command will not work.